# Android Nougat, Oreo - How to add long press action to Quick toggles?

Tags: java, android

I need some help for my app that I'm developing. Current code that I'm using, on long press it launches app info. I want to change that to launch an activity of my app.

The `Quick.java` class.

```
@TargetApi(24)
public class Quick extends TileService {

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTileAdded() {
        super.onTileAdded();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTileRemoved() {
        super.onTileRemoved();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartListening() {
        super.onStartListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopListening() {
        super.onStopListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        super.onClick();
        startActivity(Main);
    }
}
```

Just need a `onLongClick()` method on this code.

In my manifest under `<application>` tag.

```
        <service
            android:name=".Quick"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_quick"
            android:label="@string/quick_title"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**Caution :** It's 100% possible to do that in android N and O, for an example take look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesestito.ntiles&hl=en)

Comment: Are you looking for app shorcuts then follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/48594233/9287163

Comment: If you want to create a tile service like quick setting then follow this link https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/02/android-using-quick-settings-tiles.html

Comment: Well I know how to create a tile as well as how to set an activity onClick, I think you didn't read my question properly, I want to add a long click listener on the quick tile. Did you get it this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I get yes you can implement the Long click listner but here is a issue
Long clicking on your quick settings tile will, by default, go to your app’s info screen. You can override that behavior by adding an intent-filter to one of your activities like so:

`<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE_PREFERENCES"/>
</intent-filter>`

As you have done in your manifest file here a link that might be helpfull look very closely [long press quick setting tile in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723188/long-press-quick-setting-tile-in-android)